# Functions for adding nested data to model, inside or outside the model?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

suppose I have a class/model building that has a relation to the class/model wall and this again to the class/model window in a form that one building can have many surfaces and a surface can have many windows (one to many).
Now when I want to add windows to that building, maybe also only to certain surfaces, should the functions(also search functions/loops) be written inside the model? Or outside in a separate class/script that is either called from the model or called from outside?

I could imagine, when the functionality is part of the model, that it could cause problems when changes are needed in the long run.

What is the cleaner architecture/standard since both could work?
If possible can you give me a source to read more into this certain problem?

**In my case I'm using python with sqlalchemy and postgres**, but this question could also be legitimate for other programming languages.

(I hope this question is not too broad/ opinion based)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, I think this question might have been better asked in [Softwareengineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com). However, I might as well give you my few cents on this.

*As so often, it depends ...*

Generally, [encapsulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming)) is one of the core concepts in object-oriented programming.
Any change to the state of an object should be done by the object itself (although potentially triggered externally) and therefore be guaranteed to comply with the terms and conditions you defined for your object. The behavior of your object should be implemented inside your object not outside of it.

You don't want to expose your `Window`'s attribute `wall` publicly for all the world to access it directly. You want to hide it behind getters and setters. You want the `Window` to refuse being placed on a `Wall` that is passed to its `wall` setter if said `Wall` happens to be 'interior'. You don't want a `Person` object to change the `Window`'s `state` from 'open' to 'close' and vice versa directly, you want the `Person` to call the `Window`'s `open()` resp. `close()` method, e.g. to ensure internally that a closed window is not closed again.

Also, hiding implementation details can help maintaining your interface and making changes to your class transparent. Say, for example, you decide that, in addition to disallow interior walls, you now also want to prevent "normal" windows from being put into exterior walls in the basement. You can implement that check into your existing `wall` setter in `Window` and the only visible change for external code would be another potential reason for refusal ("window=normal and wall=basement" in addition to "wall=interior"). Or you want to add an attribute representing the state of cleanliness of your `Window` and, to make a proper distinction between the new `cleanliness_state` and the old 'open'/'close' `state`, you want to rename the old attribute to `open_close_state`. With your methods `open()`, `close()` (and potentially `is_open()` and `is_closed()`) reading from and writing to your 'open'/'close' `state` attribute, this change just affects your class implementation, not every piece of code that uses it.

*However!*

You might have classes that just work as some sort of collection, i.e. [data](https://refactoring.guru/smells/data-class) [classes](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0557/). These implement little to no functionality and publicly expose their attributes to be read and written by the whole world, thus broadly ignoring the concept of encapsulation. One could argue that classes/models implemented in an object-relational mapping layer, such as SQLAlchemy, are more of a data object/data class than an object in the OOP sense, especially when used mainly to persist and retrieve structured data. It is not unusual to have external code change the state of such an object or implement its functionality, like the views in the Django framework that uses its own ORM layer to implement and persist models.

*So?*

It boils down to your concrete case. You already mentioned that you consider restricting the placement of windows; probably based on properties of the windows and walls involved.

If you consider your SQLAlchemy models more than just a way of persisting your objects, go ahead and implement the behavior and change logic right away in your model. But keep in mind that a) you might end up creating conflicts with methods/properties of your model's base class and b) the attributes of your models must remain publicly exposed to maintain the functionality of your ORM layer (Although SQLAlchemy might be able to work with properties as long as both, getter and setter are defined; I have never tested that).

If you want the models to be a rather convenient method of persisting and retrieving your structured data, keep them clean and go for some utility functions or classes that implement your object's behavior and ensure its contract when being used in the code; e.g. have a function `place_window_on_wall(window: Window, wall: Wall)` that takes care of validation and restrictions when you try to reference a `Wall` object on your `Window`'s `wall` attribute. But keep in mind that changes to your model must be reflected in these functions / classes as well.

I consider both options valid; just whatever you opt for, be consistent with your decision.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification and your huge effort to explain this in detail.
Also I didn't know about the Softwareengineering stack, thaks for the hint :)